# How to determine if prolog query will give an answer or not?

Tags: prolog

Explain what will happen if we try to evaluate the query “path(a,e).”. When the query was actually run, it kept looping.I used the following method. Is it correct?

When evaluating $path(Z,e)$, if $path(Z,e):-edge(Z,e)$ was chosen, it would have returned true since there is $edge(b,e)$. But why did the program choose the recursive rule? Or am I missing something here?

[image]

Another similar question was evaluated the same way,

[image]

Comment: I disagree with closing this as a programming question. At the level being asked about here, Prolog is a resolution system, and the behaviour of resolution systems is definitely computer science.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: @Raphael Why don't you tell me where to post this question and explain why there is a tag named 'Prolog' here? And bdw I'm not asking for anybody to do my homework, I'm trying to understand the concept and want to know whether what I have understood is correct or not. Maybe you can try to read my question before copying and pasting the same comment in everything you see. I have already worked it out.

Comment: This question reads like "please explain the teacher's solution" to me which is not a mode we particularly like. Plus, you don't give attribution for the problem or the images.

Comment: @AmyCohen The misunderstanding, I think, comes from many other posters using pictures from books/etc. and just asking "explain those". Since this is (unfortunately) becoming too common here on CS, people here just assumed the pictures above to be not _your_ solution (possibly misreading the first part of your question). In other words, you put too much effort in preparing your question :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of clauses matters in Prolog: they are tried in order. So, the first clause is always tried first, and the second one would only be considered after the first clause fails. As you discovered, this never happens because the first gets stuck in a loop.

If Prolog used a breadth-first resolution algorithm, the clause order would not matter (but it would be far more consuming in terms of memory). Since instead SLD resolution is depth-first, the order does matter because of infinite paths which can lead to non-termination.

Comment: Okay so in the first example, if the last rule was written before the first rule, it would give a result right?

Comment: Yes, because $edge(b,e)$ will be found first.